# Can you find out when a new user was created in Active Directory on Windows 2003 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, user-accounts

As the question title says, I am trying to find out when a user account was created in Active Directory. The operating system is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In AD Users and Computers, inspecting the Object tab of the user account, there is a Created field.

You would need to select View menu > Advanced to be able to see the Object tab.

Comment: +1 And for those that don't like clicking: `dsquery * -filter "(SamAccountName=jscott)" -attr Name whenCreated`

Answer (score 7):

[As seen on Technet blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/01/06/how-can-i-tell-on-what-date-an-active-directory-user-account-was-created.aspx):

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://cn=ken myer, ou=Finance, dc=fabrikam, dc=com")
Wscript.Echo objUser.WhenCreated
```

[Got PowerShell?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx)

```
Get-ADUser -Identity garys -Properties whenCreated
```

Answer (score 1):

you will be get details please check below.

For User account deletion:

· On Windows 2003, we should get Event ID: 630
· On Windows 2008, we should get Event ID: 4726

For User account creation:
· On Windows 2003, we should get Event ID: 624
· On Windows 2008, we should get Event ID: 4720

Answer (score 0):

Even better example as seen on http://www.windowsnetworking.com/

```
DSQuery * “CN=TestUser,CN=Users,DC=<YourDomainName>, DC=<Com>” –Attr WhenCreated  WhenChanged
```